# Filter SQL table with max record within two specific dates range

Tags: sql

i would like to filter a table, firstly by date range and then to select the max value record within that specified period. The below code is showing records out of the specified period.

So in the example below, i have specified 1 day but it shows records for 2014-11-11 aswell.

```
    declare @BgnDate date = '2014-11-10'
    declare @EndDate date ='2014-11-10'

    SELECT EmployeeName, TargetTxDate, sum(ActualTarget) as Actual, sum(RequiredTarget) AS ReqTarget, sum(variance) AS Variance 
    FROM dbo.TargetsTx as TargetsTx
    WHERE     (Variance IN
   (SELECT    MAX (Variance) AS Expr1
   FROM          dbo.TargetsTx AS TargetsTx_1
   WHERE      (@BgnDate IS NULL OR TargetsTx_1.TargetTxDate >= @BgnDate) AND
(@EndDate IS NULL OR TargetsTx_1.TargetTxDate < DATEADD(d, 1, @EndDate))))

  group by EmployeeName,TargetTxDate
```

Comment: Which dbms are you working on?  MySQL? MSSQL? Oracle? .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you over-thinking it?  Why not something like:

```
SELECT EmployeeName, TargetTxDate, sum(ActualTarget) as Actual, sum(RequiredTarget) AS ReqTarget, sum(variance) AS Variance 
FROM dbo.TargetsTx as TargetsTx
WHERE TargetTxDate >= @BgnDate
AND TargetTxDate < @EndDate
group by EmployeeName,TargetTxDate
ORDER BY TargetTxDate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is that you have the `where` in the inner query.  You can fix it by putting it in the outer query instead.  However, I would recommend using window fucntions.

```
declare @BgnDate date = '2014-11-10'
declare @EndDate date ='2014-11-10'

SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeName ORDER BY Variance DESC) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.TargetsTx t
      WHERE  (@BgnDate IS NULL OR TargetTxDate >= @BgnDate) AND
             (@EndDate IS NULL OR TargetsTx_1.TargetTxDate < DATEADD(d, 1, @EndDate)) 
     ) e
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

I am a bit unclear why your a using `group by` or which value you want to maximize (I am guessing `variance`), but this technique will work on any variable.

Comment: received with thanks, this works aswell and thank you for the correctional advise.